# How to resume data download in other views?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, nsoutputstream

I am using AFNetworking to download an mp3 file. The download happens in a particular ViewController. Since the mp3 file is quite large, it takes a few minutes to complete the download. The problem is that when i go to another ViewController, the download stops and i have to stay on the download ViewController and wait for the download to complete. That would be frustrating for the user! Is there a way to get the download going even when the download ViewController is dismissed?
Here is the code i use for downloading:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sample.com/samplefile.mp3"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
NSString *mp3Name = @"sample.mp3";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:mp3Name];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create singleton

```
 +(id)sharedInstance
{
static dispatch_once_t pred;
static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;
}
```

And implement your downloading operation in it.

If you did not work with singletone before you should read this article [iOS design patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)

Also read this article on raywenderlich. It will give you an idea how to organize work with Web services correctly

[AFNetworking crash course](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course)

[NSOperations](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

Comment: Thanks Roma! I never worked with singletones so im gonna head to the almighty raywenderlich! Will update my answer if i get anything.

Comment: By the way, am i using the right method for downloading? Note that i want to download the file (asynchronously) in background so the user can browse the application while the file downloads.

Comment: As I can see from the code you have posted there - yes)) AFNetworking is good library for working with web services. AFNetworking is using NSOperations  which are performing in background threads

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to put a method in the ApplicationDelegate that starts the download and notifies your view controllers once your download is done. So just move your code to the applicationDelegate.

Please note: I don't think thats the best way to do it, it's much better to handle network traffic in a separate class that takes for it, but the easiest way is using the (already established) Singleton that is your ApplicationDelegate.